# Weekly new users using KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am looking for a solution that can help me identify new users every week but the comparison should be from a specific date e.g. 1st April 2023.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I have a table that contains data with date/time and email addresses. the output of the first week should show all unique records from first week but next week it should show records that were unique in the second week only. Similarly, the third week data should skip records already present in the first and the second week.

Comment: Could you share the expectations with sample input and output data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using built-in [user analytics plugins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/useranalytics)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you schedule a daily job that stores a query history. The job writes users/queries to a table.

```
.set-or-append query_history <|
  .show queries 
 | where StartedOn > ago(1d)
 | extend export_timestamp = now()
 | project StartedOn,  Duration, State, User, FailureReason, TotalCpu
```

Use the table to query for new users (first time they queried the database per calendar week)

```
query_history
 | where StartedOn > ago(720d) //limit results
 | project User, StartedOn
 | where User contains "@mycompany" //you may limit to certain mail adresses
 | summarize ms =  min(StartedOn) by User
 | extend wk = week_of_year(ms)
 | extend wk = iif(wk<=9,strcat("0",wk),tostring(wk)) //add leading zeros
 | extend cweek = strcat (format_datetime(ms, "yyyy") , "_" , wk)
 | distinct cweek, User //first time User queries db
```

Comment: I could use this approach though it took some time for me to get that. The solution works well without any doubt but user-analtics plug-in is cool for such stuff.